# Typescript typeof value in an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Trying to strongly type a data formatting function. What function does is simple,

Input:

```js
const eleOfArray = {
  a: 1,
  b: "string",
  c: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Output:

```js
const eleOfArray = {
  a: {
    value: 1,
    component: 1
  },
  b: {
    value: "string",
    component: "string"
  },
  c: {
    value: [1, 2, 3],
    component: [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```

function:

```js
export function tableDataFormatter<T>(d: T) {
 const formatedData: ITableData<T> = {}

 Object.keys(d).forEach((key: string) => {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:ban-ts-ignore
  // @ts-ignore
  formatedData[key] = {
   // tslint:disable-next-line:ban-ts-ignore
   // @ts-ignore
   value: d[key as keyof T],
   component: d[key as keyof T]
  }
 })

 return formatedData
}
```

Interface:

```js
interface ITableData<T> {
 readonly [key: keyof T]: {
  readonly component: React.ReactNode
  readonly value: T[keyof T]
 }
}
```

The problem I'm having with this code is when I use `tableDataFormatter` it shows `value` is always `string | number`.

Usage:

```js
public formatData<IBenefit> (data: ReadonlyArray<IBenefit>): ReadonlyArray<ITableData<IBenefit>> {
  return super.formatData(data).map((d: ITableData<IBenefit>) => ({
   ...d,
   stores: {
    ...d.stores,
    component: <Addon addonValues={d.stores.value} />
        // d.stores.value should be an Array but it's being shown as ReactText/string
    }
  }))
}
```

So I have to suppress the err
cause the function is working as intended and I'm clearly assigning `value` as `readonly value: T[keyof T]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ITableData<T>` interface is not valid TypeScript.  Specifically, you are trying to use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) constrained to `keyof T`, but the only allowable index signature types are `string` and `number`.  Instead you should consider using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) instead of an interface.  It will give you the mapping you want:

```
type ITableData<T> = {
  readonly [K in keyof T]: {
    readonly component: React.ReactNode
    readonly value: T[K]
  }
}
```

Note how the nested `value` property is of type `T[K]` and not `T[keyof T]`. `T[keyof T]` is going to be the union of all value types of `T` and the mapping from each key to each value is lost.  But `T[K]` means that for each key `K`, the nested `value` property is of the same type as the original property of `T` indexed by `K`.  This is the way to avoid the `string | number` problem.

Then for `tableDataFormatter()` I'd change some of the annotations and assertions like follows:

```
// strip off the readonly modifier for the top level properties
type Mutable<T> = { -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] };

// explicitly declare that the function returns ITableData<T>
export function tableDataFormatter<T extends Record<keyof T, React.ReactNode>>(
  d: T
): ITableData<T> {

  // assert that the return value will be ITableData<T> but make it
  // mutable so we can assign to it in the function without error
  const formatedData = {} as Mutable<ITableData<T>>;

  // assert that Object.keys(d) returns an array of keyof T types
  // this is not generally safe but is the same as your "as keyof T"
  // assertions and only needs to be done once.
  (Object.keys(d) as Array<keyof T>).forEach(key => {
    formatedData[key] = {
      value: d[key],
      component: d[key]
    }
  })

  return formatedData
}
```

Hopefully that works the way you expect now.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Everything else is working but I'm getting this err on `formatedData[key] = {`

err:  `Type '{ value: T[keyof T]; component: T[keyof T]; }' is not assignable to type 'ITableData<T>[keyof T]'`

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error?  I'm not using React so I can't see what the issue is.  Possibly you should restrict `T` in `tableDataFormatter<T>` to `tableDataFormatter<T extends Record<keyof T, React.ReactNode>>` because you're assuming that the properties of `T` are valid for `component`.  I edited my answer... does that help?  If not you probably need to be careful about what the `component` value will be.

Comment: Works perfectly. I also changed `component: T[K] | React.ReactNode`. Thanks alot.